# FreeBSD 10.2 unable to find package

Tags: software-installation, freebsd

When checking the ports website I find a package for `btsync`. https://freshports.org/net-p2p/btsync

When I try to install via `pkg install btsync` pkg is unable to find it

```
sudo pkg install btsync
Updating FreeBSD repository catalogue...
FreeBSD repository is up-to-date.
All repositories are up-to-date.
pkg: No packages available to install matching 'btsync' have been found in the repositories
```

Did I missed something?

Comment: I don't know why isn't available in package (maybe EULA?) but you can easily install from ports (`portsnap fetch extract` - if you don't have ports tree): `cd /usr/ports/net-p2p/btsync && make install clean`.

Comment: yeah, that's what I did but since I'm new to FreeBSD I try to understand what's going wrong

Comment: For the record: http://news.freshports.org/2015/12/29/not-all-ports-have-packages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## BitTorrent Sync is not free software.

The terms of its Copyright Licence prevent it from being made into a FreeBSD package, by disallowing anyone other than BitTorrent Incorporated itself from (re-)distributing the software.  (A BSD port does not contain the software itself; a package would.)

> **You will not** disassemble, decompile, reverse engineer or otherwise attempt to discover the source code of the Software, in whole or in part, except to the extent expressly permitted by law, or **distribute it**.

The FreshPorts doco warns that this is the case for some ports.

## Further reading

- ["What is a package?"](https://freshports.org/faq.php#package).  *Definitions for the hopelessly lazy*.  FreshPorts.
- [*End User License Agreement — Sync (Pro and API)*](https://www.getsync.com/legal/eula-proandapi).  BitTorrent Incorporated. 2015-09-08.
- [*End User License Agreement — Sync (Free)*](https://www.getsync.com/legal/eula).  BitTorrent Incorporated. 2015-02-06.
- ["Ports with Distribution Restrictions or Legal Concerns"](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/porters-handbook/porting-restrictions.html). *FreeBSD Porter's Handbook*.  The FreeBSD Documentation Project.  2014-08-08.

Comment: Ok that sounds valid. The Freshports site says `To add the package: pkg install btsync`. Is this simply an error?

Comment: http://news.freshports.org/2015/12/29/not-all-ports-have-packages/

Comment: @uzsolt yeah that post resulted from question:)

Comment: @soupdiver I thought :)